# MySql fill up table with values depending on other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-insert

In mySql I have 2 tables.

**t1** looks like

```
id      color
------------
1       red
2       green
3       blue
4       purple
```

**t2** looks like

```
id      t1_id       ship
------------------------
1       1           a
2       1           b
3       1           c
4       2           a
5       2           b
6       3           b
```

I need to fill t2 so that for each entry in t1 there are three entries in t2 - one with "a" in the ship row one with "b" in the ship row and one with "c" in it.
I don't want to have multiple entries with the same t1_id <-> ship combo. So after the query t2 should look like this.

**t2 after** the query I am looking for

```
id      t1_id       ship
------------------------
1       1           a
2       1           b
3       1           c
4       2           a
5       2           b
6       3           b
7       2           c
8       3           a
9       3           c
10      4           a
11      4           b
12      4           c
```

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put these in the table, you can use:

```
insert into t2 (t1_id, ship)
    select  t1.id, s.ship
    from t1 cross join
         (select distinct ship from t2) s left join
         t2
         on t2.t1_id = t1.id and t2.ship = s.ship
    where t2.t1_id is null;
```

This inserts the "remaining" values in `table2`.

Comment: Your `select` clause is empty.

Comment: and t.ship should be s.ship?

Comment: Thanks - that helped a lot.